# How to analyze the data model and extract the whole database/table into a csv file from the graph.db(noe4j) folder that i have?

Tags: neo4j, export-to-csv, graph-databases

How to analyze the data model and extract the whole database/table into a csv file from the graph.db(noe4j) folder that i have ?

Note: I don't want for a single cypher query. I want it for the whole database/table of the graph.db folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The neo4j Browser has an Export menu in the group of menus on the top right of every result pane. It can export the results to a number of different formats, including CSV.
2. You can use the [neo4j-shell-tools](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools), which can export to CSV.

Both of these techniques require that a neo4j server is running with your DB.

Also, they require a Cypher query that returns all the data.

For example, this query should return all data (all relationships, and all nodes that either have or do not have outgoing relationships):

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]->()
RETURN *;
```

Comment: Hi @cybersam, I am running the cypher query in browser and it says the following error:   Query cannot conclude with MATCH (must be RETURN or an update clause) (line 2, column 1 (offset: 10))
"OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]->();"

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed the query by adding the `RETURN` clause.